# Where can I get simple implementation of ERC 4337?

Tags: solidity, ethereum-wallet-dapp, erc-4337, account-abstraction

I read about https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337 few months ago.
Now, I want to start implementing it for a project .
Is there any beginner friendly repository from where I can understand this erc better ?
I have got the theoretical knowledge of working but dont know how and from where to start .
Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: I must say that particular EIP is incredibly badly written and impossible to follow. It continually mixes terminology, has poor structure and information hierarchy, uses bad English and even sloppy whitespace in the code. I had to give up. Even AI couldn't make sense of it. They're not going to get decentralization if only a handful of insiders can comprehend the docs. Instead you'll have a few large companies of technical insiders that repackage and make all this easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is the repository is made by the authors of EIP 4337:
https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction